# <img> to cover allotted space

Tags: jquery, css, html

I a attempting to span 3 images horizontally across the page.  I need these  to act like css `background-size: cover;` would.  The two outer images behave fine because their aspect ratio allows the height to fill the the empty space.  However, the bear picture does not replicate the same behavior because of its aspect ratio.

I need this picture to stretch until it reaches the full height of the box.  If it exceeds the box's width, the excess will just be hidden by `overflow: hidden;`.  How do I accomplish this is responsiveness in mind(scaling images(%) when window is resized.)

Here is my code: 
HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="albumns">
        <article>
            <div class="albumn a1">
                <%=image_tag("mount.jpg")%>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="albumn a2">
                <%=image_tag("bear.jpg")%>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="albumn a3">
                <%=image_tag("mount.jpg")%>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.albumns {
position: relative;
}
.albumn {
width: 100%;
float: none;
& img {
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: I may not be MUCH help here BUT I always recommend pre-editing your images and not making the Browser do it to increase browser performance. If I had more time at work Id explain your answer but if noone helps I will reply on my break.

Comment: I would, but I'm creating this to dynamically accept any image that the admin uploads from the dashboard of my RoR app.  I want it to adapt to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the images are variable height you'll need to fix the height of their containers. Try this:

```
.albumn{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:33%;
    height:200px; /*The height you want the images*/
}
.albumn img{
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This almost worked.  However, the width now doesn't cover its allotted space.  Is there a way to stretch the image outside of its container and crop the excess with `overflow: hidden;` so that all the space is filled up?

Comment: Oh got it!  I just switched to `height: auto;` `width: 100%;` on the img.  Thank you for the help!  I'll write a script that sets the aspect ratio based on the screen size.